# belongs_to on activerecord rendering as not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, activeadmin

I must be doing something stupid here.  I am using rails 3.2.19 with activeadmin 0.6.0.   Basically I'm trying to do a navigate down through a belongs_to association via a side bar.  I have loaded my database with text fixtures and can drill down through the association at the rails console, i.e:

```
2.1.1 :004 > Employee.first.blogposts.first
Employee Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "employees".* FROM "employees" LIMIT 1
Blogpost Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "blogposts".* FROM "blogposts" WHERE "blogposts"."employee_id" = 615722309 LIMIT 1
=> #<Blogpost id: 298486374, title: "Mine too", body: "Can we try markdown?", employee_id: 615722309, created_at: "2014-07-25 03:27:14", updated_at: "2014-07-25 03:27:14"> 
2.1.1 :005 >
```

My model associations are nothing fancy.  Basically as simple as they can be:

```
class Blogpost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employee
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :blogposts
end
```

And the same with my active admin resources.  I built these based on the documentation.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Employee do

  sidebar "Details", only: [:show, :edit] do
    ul do
      li link_to("Blogposts", admin_employee_blogposts_path(employee))
    end
  end
end

ActiveAdmin.register Blogpost do
  belongs_to :employee
end
```

I can also see the route specified when I do rake routes

```
admin_employee_blogposts GET        /admin/employees/:employee_id/blogposts(.:format)              admin/blogposts#index
```

The link on the employee page (the one defined at the Employee resource) renders without error, however when I click on it I receive:

NoMethodError in Admin::BlogpostsController#index
undefined method `find' for nil:NilClass
Parameters:
{"employee_id"=>"615722309"}

The URL specified in the browser is:

```
http://localhost:3000/admin/employees/615722309/blogposts
```

Does anybody know how to troubleshoot this?  I am certain that the particular employee ID in question has blog posts, as I demonstrated by using the rails console.  Any help anybody could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Dan Sullivan

Comment: Can you post your `index` method of your controller?

Comment: Hi, Pavan thank you for your reply.  I actually don't have an index method for my controller.  I actually don't even have a controller (other than an application controller) that exists outside of the /admin directory.  I only created models for employees and blogposts.  The employees admin resource page renders fine without a controller. If you are referring to the "Activeadmin.register Employee do" code blocks for active admin what I have posted is the complete entirety of what I have.  Thank you again for your help.

Comment: I mean your `index action` of your `Admin::BlogpostsController`.Do you have it right.

Comment: Also for sanity purposes I have posted my complete solution to github.

https://github.com/dsulli99/dors

Comment: The index action is provided by inherited resources, via active admin. What would help me troubleshoot is a backtrace.

Comment: Hi, Amiel, thank you so much for your time and efforts.  Here is the back trace you requested https://gist.github.com/dsulli99/a2fcf585608fbb9645a8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Blogpost do
  belongs_to :employee, parent_class: Employee
end
```

Comment: Thank you sir.  This was not in the documentation, although it fixed my problem 100%.

Comment: It's not documented, because it's a bug. I looked into filing an issue, but there was already one: https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources/issues/325