# Resource nesting in Active admin 1.x.x for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm using activeadmin (1.0.0.pre a2cd960) and I encountered and issue in creating subresources.

I have a User and Favorite Stores Resource.

```
#admin/user.rb
ActiveAdmin.register User do


#admin/favorite_stores.rb
ActiveAdmin.register FavoriteStores do
  menu label: "User Favorite Stores", parent: "Users"
  belongs_to :user, optional: false
```

## Rake routes

```
     batch_action_admin_user_favorite_stores POST       /admin/users/:user_id/favorite_stores/batch_action(.:format)                     admin/favorite_stores#batch_action
                   admin_user_favorite_stores GET        /admin/users/:user_id/favorite_stores(.:format)                                  admin/favorite_stores#index
                                              POST       /admin/users/:user_id/favorite_stores(.:format)                                  admin/favorite_stores#create
                new_admin_user_favorite_store GET        /admin/users/:user_id/favorite_stores/new(.:format)                              admin/favorite_stores#new
               edit_admin_user_favorite_store GET        /admin/users/:user_id/favorite_stores/:id/edit(.:format)                         admin/favorite_stores#edit
                    admin_user_favorite_store GET        /admin/users/:user_id/favorite_stores/:id(.:format)                              admin/favorite_stores#show
                                              PATCH      /admin/users/:user_id/favorite_stores/:id(.:format)                              admin/favorite_stores#update
                                              PUT        /admin/users/:user_id/favorite_stores/:id(.:format)                              admin/favorite_stores#update
                                              DELETE     /admin/users/:user_id/favorite_stores/:id(.:format)                              admin/favorite_stores#destroy
```

When I access admin/users/1/favorite_stores, this comes up.

```
NoMethodError in Admin::FavoriteStoresController#index
undefined method `favorite_stores' for #<User:0x0000010938ccf0>
```

Comment: did you define associations in class definitions outside ActiveAdmin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this by adding this line to the ActiveAdmin model

```
ActiveAdmin.register FavoriteStore do
  belongs_to :user, parent_class: User
```

SRC: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25028452/3414157

Answer (score 0):

#### Hello

Please use nested belongs_to [Support nested belongs_to #376](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/376)

```
ActiveAdmin.register FavoriteStores do
  controller do
    nested_belongs_to :users
  end
  menu false
end
```

Please also check your routes outside defined in config/routes.rb.

Hope this will work :)

Comment: This didn't help. Thanks anyway. @mehul